# HashMap doesn't write in the database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, hashmap

I try to write in my database but only the sender and the message is written.I don't understand why this happens.I think the problem is where I use the sendMessage.I think the problem is that I don't have something to read/write the primary key for the other users.

The Activity where I written in the database the messages.

```
public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView username;
    FirebaseUser fuser;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    Intent intent;
    ImageButton btn_send;
    EditText text_send;
    MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    List<Chat> mchat;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView ( R.layout.activity_message );
        btn_send=findViewById ( R.id.btn_send );
        text_send=findViewById ( R.id.editText );
        recyclerView=findViewById ( R.id.recycler_view1 );
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize ( true );
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager ( getApplicationContext () );
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd ( true );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( linearLayoutManager );







            username=findViewById ( R.id.username6 );


            intent=getIntent ();
            final String userid=intent.getStringExtra ( "FIRST NAME " );
        fuser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance ().getCurrentUser ();
        reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ("users");
        reference.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener () {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange (@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {



                for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren ()){
                    User user=snapshot.getValue (User.class);


                    assert user!=null;
                    assert fuser!=null;
                    if(!fuser.getUid ().equals ( user.getFirstName () )){
                        username.setText ( user.getFirstName () );



                    }

                }
                readMessages ( fuser.getUid (),userid );

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled (@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        } );
        btn_send.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick (View view) {
                String msg=text_send.getText ().toString ();
                if(!msg.equals ( "" )){
                    sendMessage ( fuser.getUid (),msg,userid );
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText ( MessageActivity.this,"You can't send empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
                }
                text_send.setText ( "" );
            }

        } );


        }
private void sendMessage(String sender,String receiver,String message)
{
    DatabaseReference reference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ();
    HashMap<String,Object> hashMap=new HashMap<> (  );
    hashMap.put ( "sender",sender );
    hashMap.put ( "receiver",receiver );
    hashMap.put ( "message",message );
    reference.child ( "Chats" ).push ().setValue ( hashMap );
}
```

I expect that receiver to be written in the database.

Comment: after .serValue() in your map, put an onCompleteListener and check for the failure if it happens there

Comment: You are not even using your own method right. sendMessage ( fuser.getUid (),msg,userid ); should be sendMessage (fuser.getUid (),userid, msg);

Comment: Tried to change the order and forget to modify. I forget to modify.